# SVN export not working when called from Python's subprocess.call

Tags: python, svn

I've the following function to fetch a file from the Subversion repositorio:

```
def getFileSVN(remoteFile, localFile):
    remoteFile = SVN_URL + '/' + remoteFile
    command = '{0} export {1} {2}'.format(SVN, remoteFile, localFile)
    ret = subprocess.call(command.split())
    if ret == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The function is called with:

```
ret = getFileSVN(branches/branch/somefile, /tmp/tmpdir/somefile)
```

But it always fails with:

```
svn: Can't open '/tmp/tmpdir/tempfile.tmp': No such file or directory
```

I can't find where my error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does tmpdir exist? I don't use SVN myself but it could be that it doesn't create the folder before trying to create the file.

Comment: You're right, the object calling this function was created before the directory. Thanks.